# separate external artifacts repository and project artifacts repository in maven

Tags: maven, build, gradle, continuous-integration

As a CI engineer I want all my maven jobs to have 1 local repository with external artifacts - aka projects 3rd and 2nd party dependencies, plugins...
This would save me tons of build time and disk space avoiding downloading from remote repository.

On the other hand, each build job is supposed to have isolated repository to write to.

Is there a way to work 2 separate local maven reposiotories: one for external artifacts and the other for internal?

Another option is to seperate them.by groupId.

Do you know if Gradle support such logic?

Comment: Check the Maven settings file documentation. Allows you to specify the location of the local repository. See: http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Simple_Values

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve here. Gradle always downloads third-party dependencies into its own cache (not into a local Maven repo).